# Identify connected projects with same staff in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if two projects are connected through the persons working on them. A new df should indicate how any two projects are connected.

Either directly connected: at least one person from the first project worked on the second project (`connection=0`),

or indirectly connected: one person from the first project worked with a person from the second project on another project (`connection=1`).

The original df looks like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'person':['A','A','B','B','C','C','D'],
...                     'project':['P1','P2','P1','P4','P2','P3','P3'],
...                     'year':[2003,2004,2003,2006,2004,2005,2005]})
>>> df_1
  person project  year
0      A      P1  2003
1      A      P2  2004
2      B      P1  2003
3      B      P4  2006
4      C      P2  2004
5      C      P3  2005
6      D      P3  2005
```

The newly created df_2 should look like this:

```
>>> df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'first_project':['P1','P1','P1','P2','P2'],
...                      'second_project':['P2','P3','P4','P3','P4'],
...                      'connection':[0,1,0,0,1]})
>>> df_2
  first_project second_project  connection
0            P1             P2           0
1            P1             P3           1
2            P1             P4           0
3            P2             P3           0
4            P2             P4           1
```

Any idea on what would be the fastest way? There are several million projects in df_1
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For `connection=0`, you can merge the dataframe with itself on person and remove duplicate projects, the rest will be projects having `connection=0`.

Here is how you would do it:

```
df_connection_zero = df.merge(df, left_on="person", right_on="person", suffixes = ("_first","_second"))
df_connection_zero = df_connection_zero[df_connection_zero["project_first"] !=df_connection_zero["project_second"]].drop_duplicates(subset=["person"])
df_connection_zero = df_connection_zero[["project_first","project_second"]]
df_connection_zero["connection"] = 0
```

We'll get:

```
 project_first project_second  connection
            P1             P2           0
            P1             P4           0
            P2             P3           0
```

For `connection=1`, it seems to be a bit more complicated, I'll let you know if I find how.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I went for this: `df_2 = pd.merge(df_1,df_1, on='person', suffixes = ("_first","_second")).query("project != project2").reset_index(drop=True)`. Given that several persons may have worked on the same projects, I drop duplicates `df_2 = df_2[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df_2[['project_first','project_second']].values,1)).duplicated()]`. For the second connection, I probably use Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm following this suggestion: [link](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-in-python-d955744c7064). Do you know a more convenient way?

Comment: For the second case of indirectly connected projects, it could have more than one project in common ? i.e. 2 or 3 projects between the two persons ?